# Incorrectly displayed text in IE8, all other browsers ok

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have a problem on my page.

Text is a little bit too high and a bit on the left on Internet Explorer.

How to correct this ?

```
.tagibg {
    font-size:11px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
```

and in IE7.css (for all IE versions):

```
.tagibg {
    font-variant:small-caps;
}
```

Part of my php code:

```
$czytnik->czytaj_szablon('<table>','<tr><td><a href="#link" target="_self"><font class="tytul4">#tytul</font></a><br />
<p /><font class="tytulmalykom">Dodano: #data | #ilosc_wyswietlen odsłon | #ilosc_komentarzy komentarzy</font><br />
<br />#obrazek_l0<br />#tresc<br />
<font class="tagibg">#tagi #zrodlo</font><div style="clear: both;"></div><p />
</td></tr>','</table><div class="old">#strony_2</div>');
echo $czytnik->wypisz();
?>
```

Comment: Show us your code. Without showing us your code no one will help.

Comment: Try adding a few more adverts onto the site :p

I think it may be a table padding issue. Using tables for the layout the way you have done is not considered good practice anymore.

Tables should only really be used on websites to display tabular data.

If you change to a layout using divs, articles or sections you'll get on a lot better I think.

Comment: I know, but it's hard to replace it on so many pages.

Comment: Have you tried `line-height` property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed it a little bit:

```
<div class="tagibg">#tagi #zrodlo</div><div style="clear: both;"></div><p />
```

and then added:

```
.tagibg {
font-variant:small-caps;
padding-top:10px;
```

}